# Confused about two steps of the smoothness for functions satisfying the mean value property

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Evans page 28. He shows that a function satisfying the mean value property is smooth.

He uses mollification, i.e. let $u^\epsilon = \eta_\epsilon * u$

\begin{align*}
u^\epsilon(x)&=\int_U \eta_\epsilon(x-y)u(y)dy\\
&= \frac{1}{\epsilon^n}\int_U\eta\left(\frac{|x-y|}{\epsilon}\right)u(y) dy\\
&= \frac{1}{\epsilon^n}\int_0^\epsilon\eta\left(\frac{r}{\epsilon}\right)\left(\int_{\partial B(x,r)} u dS\right) dr\\
\end{align*}
How is that last step done. I was thinking mean value theorem here, but this gives for any $B(y,r)\subset U$:
\begin{align*}
=\frac{1}{\epsilon^n}\int_U\eta\left(\frac{|x-y|}{\epsilon}\right)(-\!\!\!\!\!\!\int_{\partial B(y,r)} u dS) dy&=
\end{align*}
and I can't get this to equal the above.

Secondly, they then get from the above the following equality:
$$\frac{1}{\epsilon^n}u(x)\int_0^\epsilon \eta(r/\epsilon) n\alpha(n)r^{n-1}dr=u(x)\int_{B(0,\epsilon)} \eta_\epsilon dy$$
and I just can't see how transforming from $dr$ to $dy$ destroys the $n\alpha(n) r^{n-1}$ terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}\frac{1}{ε^n} &∫_U\eta(|x-y|/ε ) u(y) \ dy \\
 &\overset{1}{=} \frac{1}{ε^n} ∫_{B(x,\epsilon)}\eta(|x-y|/ε ) u(y) \ dy \\
 &\overset{2}{=} \frac{1}{ε^n}∫_{r=0}^ε \eta(r/
ε)∫_{\partial B(x,r)}u \ dS \ dr\\ 
&\overset{}{=} \frac{1}{ε^n}∫_{r=0}^ε n\alpha(n)r^{n-1}\eta(r/
ε)\left(\frac1{n\alpha(n)r^{n-1}}∫_{\partial B(x,r)}u \ dS\right) \ dr \\
&\overset{3}{=} \frac{1}{ε^n}∫_{r=0}^ε n\alpha(n)r^{n-1}\eta(r/
ε) u(x) \ dr \\ 
&\overset{4}{=} \frac{1}{ε^n}∫_{r=0}^ε \eta(r/
ε) u(x) \ ∫_{\partial B(x,r)}1 \ dS \ dr \\ 
&\overset{5}{=} u(x)\frac{1}{ε^n}∫_{B(x,ε)}\eta(|x-y|/\varepsilon) \ dy \\
&\overset{}{=} u(x)∫_{B(0,ε)}\eta_ε \ dy \end{align}

1. support of $\eta(\cdot/\varepsilon)$
2. [co-area formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formula)(see the first bullet point under "applications")
3. mean value property
4. area of the surface of the $r$-sphere around $x$
5. co-area formula

Comment: That's oddly beautiful. Thank you!